# Leetcode:Balanced Binary Tree .Is my program O(n^2)? It runs faster than O(n)

Tags: algorithm

Here is the problem:https://oj.leetcode.com/problems/balanced-binary-tree/
first I write the solution whick I think is O(n^2) like this:

```
class Solution {
public:
    int calc(TreeNode *p){
        if (p==NULL) return 0;
        int a=calc(p->left);
        int b=calc(p->right);
        if (a>b) return a+1; else return b+1;
    }
    bool isBalanced(TreeNode *root) {
        if (root==NULL) return true;
        return (isBalanced(root->left) && isBalanced(root->right) && abs(calc(root->left)-calc(root->right))<=1);

    }
};
```

then I write a O(n) solution :
class Solution {

```
public:
    int check(TreeNode *p){
        if (p==NULL) return 0;
        int l=check(p->left);
        int r=check(p->right);
        if( l==-99 || r==-99 || abs(l-r)>1) return -99;
        return max(l,r)+1;
    }
    bool isBalanced(TreeNode *root) {
        if (root==NULL) return true;
        return check(root)!=-99;

    }
};
```

Both got Accepted. First one runtime :56ms, second one is 100ms sometimes 400+ms.
Why the O(n^2) if faster than the O(n)?

Comment: Your first solution is a worst-case O(n^2), or probably never achieves O(n^2); the average should be much better than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Big-O notation tells you nothing about run time for specific values of N, it only tells you how the run time will *grow* as N increases.

It is not unnatural for a O(n) to outperform O(n^2) for a specific N.

Consider this, a piece of code that *always* takes 10 minutes to complete is O(1).